# Issues implementing moveable platforms in XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xna, xna-4.0

I am currently following this tutorial: http://robotfootgames.com/xna-tutorials/78-xna-platformer-starter-kit-movable-platforms

Which is based on this code sample: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/platformer

Everything seems to work except this block of code, which gives me a bunch of errors:

```
private Rectangle HandleCollision(Rectangle bounds, TileCollision collision, Rectangle tileBounds)
{
Vector2 depth = RectangleExtensions.GetIntersectionDepth(bounds, tileBounds);
if (depth != Vector2.Zero)
{
    float absDepthX = Math.Abs(depth.X);
    float absDepthY = Math.Abs(depth.Y);

    // Resolve the collision along the shallow axis.
    if (absDepthY &lt; absDepthX || collision == TileCollision.Platform)
    {
        // If we crossed the top of a tile, we are on the ground.
        if (previousBottom &lt;= tileBounds.Top)
            isOnGround = true;

        // Ignore platforms, unless we are on the ground.
        if (collision == TileCollision.Impassable || IsOnGround)
        {
            // Resolve the collision along the Y axis.
            Position = new Vector2(Position.X, Position.Y + depth.Y);

            // Perform further collisions with the new bounds.
            bounds = BoundingRectangle;
        }
    }
    else if (collision == TileCollision.Impassable) // Ignore platforms.
    {
        // Resolve the collision along the X axis.
        Position = new Vector2(Position.X + depth.X, Position.Y);

        // Perform further collisions with the new bounds.
        bounds = BoundingRectangle;
    }
 }
 return bounds;
}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve the below error (I tried myself and it just seems to result in the code breaking further):

```
&lt;
```

"The name 'It' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like someone didn't escape their HTML correctly. Just replace every `&lt;` with `<` and the code should work.

Comment: Ah damn it, I had a feeling this wasn't something C# related after I spent a hour trying to fix it. I'll mark this as the answer in a few mins, thanks!